# Error when calling the same function more than once

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I wrote a php function which should return the Highest Primary Key value. It works fine when i call the function once but i get error when I call it twice.
Following is my output:
*0* //Correct answer for the first function call
//Following error for the second function call
**Notice: Undefined variable: DBH**

**Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object**

here is the code for my function file:

```
<?php function getPKofLastInsert($event)
{
require_once('connection.php');

$Q="";
switch ($event)
{

        case "c":

            $Q= "SELECT `PK` FROM `c` ORDER BY `PK` DESC LIMIT 0,1";
            break;

        case "s":
            $Q = "SELECT `PK` FROM `s` ORDER BY `PK` DESC LIMIT 0,1";
            break;

        case "w":
            $Q = "SELECT `PK` FROM `w` ORDER BY `PK` DESC LIMIT 0,1";
            break;
}
    if(!$result= $DBH->query($Q))
        {
            die("error");
        }
        else if($result->num_rows==0)
        {   return 0;   }
        else
        {
            $row= $result->fetch_asoc();
            $t=$row['PK'];
            $result->free();
    //$DBH->close();    
            return $t;
        }
}

?>

<?php

print getPKofLastInsert("c");
print getPKofLastInsert("c");


?>
```

here is my **connection.php** file:

```
$DBH = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DB);
if ($DBH->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

At some forums I have found that:

```
$DBH->close();
```

should work, in my case it doesn't p.s i don't think i need that because i am using require_once() and i obviously need my database handle $DBH for use in other functions.... Kindly help, Thanks

Comment: You might need to put the require_once outside the function call. It might not be being included on the second call, because it'd already been required.

Comment: @andrewsi this is actually the answer

Comment: why bother with order/limit? `SELECT MAX(PK) FROM W` is all you need.

Comment: thanks @MarcB for pointing out the improvement in query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `require_once()` instead of `require()`, it only runs that code the first time.

There are a few options to fix this:

1. Change to `require('connection.php')`. This will open a new DB connection each time you call the function, so you should uncomment `$DBH->close()` to keep from having lots of connections.
2. Declare `$DBH` static in `connection.php`, so it will keep its value across calls.
3. Put `require_once('connection.php')` outside the function, and pass `$DBH` as an argument to the function.
4. Put `require_once('connection.php')` outside the function, and put `global $DBH;` in the function.